# Construct / find the simplest function based on data

Tags: functions, regression, interpolation

Let's say I have these 7 natural numbers (all between 0 and 255):

```
255, 23, 45, 32, 87, 52, 146
```

How can I find a function F(x) that, once computed, gives me back these values, ie.

```
f(1) = 255
f(2) = 23
f(3) = 45
...
```

I'm not sure what's the technical term to use for this, but I trust you got the picture.

All the above numbers are **just examples** (except that all values are natural number between 0 and 255).

All I **really** care is that I need the **simplest** possible function that can give me such result, be it polynomial, quartic or any other type of function.

I used to be good at math, but it's been at least 10 years since I took my last math class, so please bear with me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lagrange interpolation provides a nice *general* polynomial answer. However, suppose that $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=4$, $f(3)=8$, and so on. Then $f(n)=2^n$ is a  simple formula, while the Lagrange interpolation polynomial is fairly messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want to use [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). This formula gives the polynomial with the  smallest degree that fits your data points exactly. You can find the formula for the Lagrange polynomial at the link, and also there are online calculators that will calculate it for you.

For instance, when I plug your data points 
[1, 255], [2,23], [3,45], [4,32], [5,87], [6,52], [7,146] 
into [this calculator](http://www.solvemymath.com/online_math_calculator/interpolation.php), I get back the result:

$$f(x)={1291x^6-31029x^5+296455x^4-1434195x^3+3689254x^2-4761696x+2423520\over 720}$$